# Dropdown list appears (on hover) even when it's hidden inside the mobile menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my navbar I have a li item that opens a dropdown menu when someone hovers over it. In small screens I have a hamburger menu that hides it.

The problem is that in mobile view, even though the li item is "hidden" inside the menu when someone hovers over its position on screen it appears (even though it is hidden inside the menu).

I think that this probably happens because I set "visibility: hidden;" but I don't know how else to do it.

I mean I want to dropdown when someones hover it on desktop view but on mobile I want to dropdown only if someones open the menu and then hover over it (or maybe click on it).

To save space I included below only the code that I find more relevant.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
      if ($(".item").hasClass("active")) {
          $(".item").removeClass("active");
      } else {
          $(".item").addClass("active");
      }
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  background: #3e3e40;
  padding: 0 20px;
 
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
  color: rgb(189, 169, 136);
}
nav a:focus{
outline: 0;
}
.logo a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;

}
.menu li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.logo img{
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;

}

.logo{
  padding: 0;
  flex: 1;
}
.toggle a {
  font-size: 20px;
}
nav, ul, li{
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

/* Mobile menu */
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.toggle {
order: 1;
}
.cart{
  order:1
}
.item {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  order: 3;
  display: none;
}
.login-info{
  order:2
}
.item.active {
  display: block;
  
}

/* Navbar Toggle */
.toggle {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.bars {
  background: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}
.bars:before,
.bars:after {
  background: #999;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.bars:before {
  top: 5px;
}
.bars:after {
  top: -5px;
}


/*---------------dropdown li css-------------------*/
.dropdwn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

.dropdwn-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  
  padding: 12px 16px;
  right: 39.5%;
  z-index: 1;
 height: 0;
}
.dropdwn-content a{
  color: #3e3e40;
}
.dropdwn-content li{
  color: #3e3e40;
}
.dropdwn-content a:focus{
 outline:0;
}

.dropdwn:hover .dropdwn-content {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in;
}
/*------font awesome and pseudo classes navbar-----*/
.fa-lg{
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 26px;
  position: relative;
}
.fa-lg::before{
  content: '';
  border: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 43px;
  height: 43px;
  right:14px;
  top:-8px
 
}
.badge:after{
  content:attr(value);
  font-size:18px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(92, 148, 166);
  border-radius:50%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  position:relative;
  left:-2px;
  top:-15px;
  opacity:0.9;
}
.pseudo::before{
  content:attr(username);
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: auto;
  height: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  }


.circle{
  border: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
 
}

/* Tablet menu */
@media all and (min-width: 468px) {
  .menu {
      justify-content: center;
  }
}

/* Desktop menu */
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .item {
      display: block;
      width: auto;
  }
  .toggle {
      display: none;
  }

  .item {
      order: 2;
  }

  .menu li {
      padding: 15px 10px;
  }

 .dropdwn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdwn-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;

}

.dropdwn:hover .dropdwn-content {
  display: block;
  color: white;

}
.signup{
  padding-right: 2rem;
}


.pseudo::before{
  width: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.pseudo::after{
  content:'';
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: auto;
  height: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=604800" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="logo"><a href="{%url 'home'%}"><img src="" alt="Company's logo"><a/></li>
    
    
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="">Store</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdwn item">
      <span class="item">Categories</span>
        
        <ul class="dropdwn-content">
         
          <li><a href="{{category.get_url}}">Product1</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{category.get_url}}">Product2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   
    <li class="item">
      <a href="" class="pseudo" username="Welcome Guest">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href=""class="signup">Signup </a>
    </li >

    <li class="item">
      <form action=""  method='GET' >
        
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="keyword">
        <button type="submit" >
          
        </button>
      </form>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle"><span class="bars"></span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: You should make a minimum working example so I can play around with it

Comment: I updated the code to run on the page. Sorry I'm new and I don't know all the tricks of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

## I solved it using media queries

*Adjust for whatever pixle size you want*

### Code Pen Link:

[Click Here](https://codepen.io/WakyWayne/pen/abqwGzB)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=604800" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="logo"><a href="{%url 'home'%}"><img src="" alt="Company's logo"><a/></li>
    
    
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="">Store</a>
    </li>
<!--     dropdwn -->
    <li class=" item dropdwn">
      <span class="item">Categories</span>
        
        <ul class="dropdwn-content disapear">
         
          <li class="disapear"><a href="{{category.get_url}}">Product1</a></li>
          <li class="disapear"><a href="{{category.get_url}}">Product2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   
    <li class="item">
      <a href="" class="pseudo" username="Welcome Guest">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href=""class="signup">Signup </a>
    </li >

    <li class="item">
      <form action=""  method='GET' >
        
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="keyword">
        <button type="submit" >
          
        </button>
      </form>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle"><span class="bars"></span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

```
nav {
  background: #3e3e40;
  padding: 0 20px;
 
}
@media all and (max-width:800px){
  .disapear{
    display: none;
  }
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
  color: rgb(189, 169, 136);
}
nav a:focus{
outline: 0;
}
.logo a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;

}
.menu li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.logo img{
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;

}

.logo{
  padding: 0;
  flex: 1;
}
.toggle a {
  font-size: 20px;
}
nav, ul, li{
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

/* Mobile menu */
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.toggle {
order: 1;
}
.cart{
  order:1
}
.item {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  order: 3;
  display: none;
}
.login-info{
  order:2
}
.item.active {
  display: block;
  
}

/* Navbar Toggle */
.toggle {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.bars {
  background: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}
.bars:before,
.bars:after {
  background: #999;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.bars:before {
  top: 5px;
}
.bars:after {
  top: -5px;
}


/*---------------dropdown li css-------------------*/
.dropdwn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

.dropdwn-content {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  
  padding: 12px 16px;
  right: 39.5%;
  z-index: 1;
 height: 0;
}
.dropdwn-content a{
  color: #3e3e40;
}
.dropdwn-content li{
  color: #3e3e40;
}
.dropdwn-content a:focus{
 outline:0;
}


  
  @media all and (min-width: 800px){
    .dropdwn:hover .dropdwn-content {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in;
  }
}
/*------font awesome and pseudo classes navbar-----*/
.fa-lg{
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 26px;
  position: relative;
}
.fa-lg::before{
  content: '';
  border: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 43px;
  height: 43px;
  right:14px;
  top:-8px
 
}
.badge:after{
  content:attr(value);
  font-size:18px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(92, 148, 166);
  border-radius:50%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  position:relative;
  left:-2px;
  top:-15px;
  opacity:0.9;
}
.pseudo::before{
  content:attr(username);
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: auto;
  height: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  }


.circle{
  border: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
 
}

/* Tablet menu */
@media all and (min-width: 468px) {
  .menu {
      justify-content: center;
  }
}

/* Desktop menu */
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .item {
      display: block;
      width: auto;
  }
  .toggle {
      display: none;
  }

  .item {
      order: 2;
  }

  .menu li {
      padding: 15px 10px;
  }

 .dropdwn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdwn-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;

}

.dropdwn:hover .dropdwn-content {
  display: block;
  color: white;

}
.signup{
  padding-right: 2rem;
}


.pseudo::before{
  width: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.pseudo::after{
  content:'';
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: auto;
  height: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

}
```

Comment: Yes but in small screens you can't open the dropdown list after entering the mobile menu. My problem is that in order to show the dropdown menu in small screens I get the hover effect even when the mobile menu is closed. I want to see the dropdown in ssmall screens only if I open the menu and hover or click on the dropdown li.

Comment: Well, there isn't a hover option on mobile so I wouldn't worry to much about that. If you add a click event handler you should be able to toggle the classes as you need so that the menu will show on click. I think am struggling to understand your question.